# AttributeError: 'website' object has no attribute 'get_active_website_setting' in odoo 13

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo-13

I am new to odoo. And I had successfully imported a copy of the dump database to PostgreSQL. After importing dump database the following error occurs.

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 333, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_web_login_7
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_5
AttributeError: 'website' object has no attribute 'get_active_website_setting'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 234, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 809, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 342, in checked_call
    result.flatten()
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1236, in flatten
    self.response.append(self.render())
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1229, in render
    return env["ir.ui.view"].render_template(self.template, self.qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1191, in render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 344, in render
    return super(View, self).render(values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 27, in render
    return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1199, in render
    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 58, in render
    result = super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 260, in render
    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 340, in _compiled_fn
    raise QWebException("Error to render compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
odoo.addons.base.models.qweb.QWebException: 'website' object has no attribute 'get_active_website_setting'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 333, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_web_login_7
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_5
AttributeError: 'website' object has no attribute 'get_active_website_setting'
Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'website' object has no attribute 'get_active_website_setting'
Template: web.login
Path: /t/t/t
Node: <t t-set="signup_settings" t-value="website.get_active_website_setting()"/>**
```

Could anyone please guide me to solve this